# Unable to access Samba, Apache2 on Ubuntu Server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, samba

I've got a PC running Ubuntu 20.04 that I used as my home server with a VM, Samba, webserver, DDNS, SSH etc but randomly it just stopped showing up on my local network for half the services.

I can no longer connect to my Samba shares from any devices (connection timed out) but locally on the machine via 127.0.0.1 they appear just fine. Apache no longer works, I can't access my webpage internally on the network or externally (HTTP port 80).

The machine can access the internet just fine, can be pinged from other devices and I can SSH in just fine, I haven't changed anything on the router and it shows up just fine under 192.168.1.3. I can also perform remote iperf3 tests to it just fine so it isn't a router/ISP issue I believe (although the results are much slower than they should be)

All the services mentioned above are running on the machine fine, I reinstalled apache2 and then tried NGINX and can confirm they both bind to port 80 with `netstat -plant | grep 80` which gave `tcp  0   0 0.0.0.0:80  0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  229301/nginx: maste`

I'm totally stuck as to what is causing this, everything else on my network works fine and the only settings I have for this PC are a couple of external port forwards for 80, 433 and 5201 setup on the router. I'm currently connected to my home network over VPN but the issues are present over VPN and when connected to local Wi-Fi.

Any help to solve this would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks

ifconfig gives:

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 192.168.1.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
inet6 fe80::5a95:86f3:75e2:9524  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
ether 4c:72:b9:57:42:b7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
RX packets 5399190  bytes 1320272608 (1.3 GB)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 1003884  bytes 425572182 (425.5 MB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7c00000-f7c20000

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
RX packets 353136  bytes 37884073 (37.8 MB)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 353136  bytes 37884073 (37.8 MB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Update: Managed to get Apache2 back up and working after reinstalling and wiping all my config and then reverting to the default netplan YAML file removing DNS/static IPs etc. Still nothing for SAMBA or Glances monitoring webserver. Guess it's a network config error caused by me at some stage, I'll keep having a look and post if I can fix it in case anyone else has the same issue :)

Comment: firewall (iptables, nft, ufw) ?

Comment: Changed then when I first setup the machine to get everything working - had a look and everything is still set and (should be) working